# rails ahoy gem - primary key id and autoincrement give duplicate entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I meet few problems with ahoy visit model in my rails app

I have a lot of

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '$$' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `visits`
```

where $$ is a number

when I print last records

```
Visits=Visit.find(:all, :order => "started_at desc", :limit => 5)
Visits.each do |visit| puts "#{visit.id} -- #{visit.started_at}" end
```

display is

99904352 -- 2018-02-01 11:32:51 UTC

8918 -- 2018-02-01 09:59:04 UTC

90866 -- 2018-02-01 09:09:10 UTC

99904351 -- 2018-02-01 09:03:00 UTC

99904350 -- 2018-02-01 08:58:24 UTC

I have already try to reset autoincrement value

```
ALTER TABLE visits AUTO_INCREMENT = max_value+1;
```

without success ..

any ideas ? I would like to avoid dump/drop/reload DB

thanks !

Comment: what is max_value? 99904352? Why don't you order by the id? Maybe there's a larger one.

Comment: order by id didn't show the problem, that was the max value at the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok
I had a false before_create that try to set id with uuid instead of integer .. I have comment it .. I have to wait but I believe that was my problem ..

my bad :p

Comment: this was causing my issue :S

Answer (score 3):

When you find a duplicate key error, such as **Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '$$' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `visits`**, you should check two things:

- if you insert records setting the key mannually
- if the autoincrement value is not the larger key.

You must of course change your program to avoid inserting records setting the key mannually, and you must update the autoincrement value, to the next available one. To do this, search for the largest value and set it to the next one.

```
Select max(id) from visits;
ALTER TABLE visits AUTO_INCREMENT = max_value + 1;
```

Comment: the ahoy_matey gem doesn't need to specify id, the other model ahoy::event has not the problem